# how to override main methods for Map

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to implement a Map interface and want to override its main methods, but my method put doesn't work. Basically I can't compare strings for some reason.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MapImpl implements Map {

    private HashMap<Object, Object> aMap = new HashMap<>();
    private int size = 0;


    //should return value object on success put
    @Override
    public Object put(Object key, Object value){
        String middleString = (String)(aMap.get(key));
        String valueString = (String)(value);
        if (middleString.equals(valueString)){
        aMap.put(key,value);

        } else {
            aMap.put(key,value);
            size++;
        }

        return value;
    }

    //should return value by key
  

      @Override
       public Object get(Object key) {
           return aMap.get(key);


    }

    //should return count of all value objects in the map
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    //should return value object on success removing it by the key
    @Override
    public Object remove(Object key){
        String returnedValue = (String)(aMap.get(key));
        aMap.remove(key);
        size--;
        return returnedValue;
    }

}
```

In `put` I want to compare if there is a key in my Map by making values as strings, but when the value is null, it doesn't convert to a string, so I can't compare it neither ide doesn't allow me to put null in equals or put `==` operand to compare strings in if statement.

Comment: I don't understand what "compare if there is a key in my Map by making values as strings" means.

Comment: First, start by learning about generics. Your code will be much simpler if you use them correctly (e.g., by declaring your class as `MapImpl<V> implements Map<String, V>`).

Comment: in "put" I want to make so that if aMap.get(key) is a null, then run aMap.put(key, value) and do size++, if aMap.get(key) has a value, then it has to be replaced with a value, that is given as a parametr to "put" and size doesn't increase. and if aMap.get(key) the same as the value, then no actions taken.

Comment: I implement not from  THE Map that is given by java core, but I implement from some randomly made interface called Map with no methods declared, so I need to make them myself

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
if (Objects.equals(middleString, valueString)) {
```

instead of `middleString.equals(valueString)`. The [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) method checks if the two reference values you pass in are null, or point to the same object, or point to objects that are equivalent according to the equals method.

If you were to write the same checks yourself, it would look like:

```
if (middleString == valueString || (middleString != null && middleString.equals(valueString))
```

Comment: yes, it would, exactly what I need, but this doesn't work. So I need the same idea, but the one that works

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out the issue and now it works! the code was almost perfect, however there was a missing ! after && so it had to be `if  (middleString == valueString || (middleString != null && !middleString.equals(valueString)))`